How to get parentId in lightning component override of new button in child object
I am using an aura component to override the New and Edit actions of a custom sObject.
Let's call it Child_Object__c. This object is related to a parent sObject (let's call it Parent_Object__c) with a master-detail relationship.
Is it possible to obtain the Id of the parent record in the aura component if I click on New in the related list on the parent record's view page?
The force:hasRecordId only returns the specific object's Id if I clicked on Edit. But on New, of course there is no recordId but I need the parentId, so I can add some logic.
I found some messy workarounds for this, but I'm asking here to see if there is an update to that and there is a better way

Yes "messy workarounds" seems to be all that is available at present. I'm using the following approach successfully.
I have this Aura component (as lightning:isUrlAddressable was not available for LWCs but it is now - see Navigate to a URL-Addressable Lightning Web Component):
<aura:component
    description="genericActionOverride"
    implements="lightning:actionOverride, lightning:isUrlAddressable"
    >

    <!-- Do all the work in the LWC; no LWC lightning:actionOverride at the moment (Sep 2024) -->
    <c:genericActionOverrideDelegate
        pageReference="{!v.pageReference}">
    </c:genericActionOverrideDelegate>

</aura:component>

that wraps this LWC (that I've removed quite a bit of logic from as it handled multiple cases; I've cut it down to the simple parent Id case):
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { encodeDefaultFieldValues } from "lightning/pageReferenceUtils";

import PARENT_ID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/<<objectApiName>.<<fieldApiName>>';

/**
 * The aim here is to fill in the missing parent Id.
 *  * Called from an Aura component that implements the lightning:actionOverride
 * interface that is currently not available in LWC (Sep 2024).
 */
export default class GenericActionOverrideDelegate extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    /**
     * This is expected to be a normal standard object page reference with the preceding
     * page reference encoded in base 64 in the inContextOfRef state value.
     */
    @api
    set pageReference(value) {

        this._pageReference = value;

        // Component isn't necessarily re-created so reset
        this.parentRecordId = null;

        // See e.g. https://sfdclesson.com/2019/11/23/get-parent-record-id-from-lightning-url/
        if (this.pageReference) {
            let base64Context = this.pageReference?.state?.inContextOfRef;
            if (base64Context) {
                if (base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) {
                    base64Context = base64Context.substring(2);
                    this.originalPageReference = JSON.parse(atob(base64Context));

                    // Extract whatever is needed here; just the parent id in this example
                    // This data can be used to do further querying bofore the navigation if needed
                    const recordId = this.originalPageReference?.attributes?.recordId;
                    this.parentRecordId = recordId;
                    this.ready = () => this.connected && this.parentRecordId;
                }
            }
        }

        this.navigateWhenReady();
    }
    get pageReference() {
        return this._pageReference;
    }
    _pageReference;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.connected = true;
        this.navigateWhenReady();
    }

    connected;              // Can't navigate until connected
    parentRecordId;         // This is the missing value that is needed

    ready = () => false;    // Ready or not

    async navigateWhenReady() {

        if (!this.ready()) return;

        // This is shown under the modal and so displayed when Cancel is clicked
        // See e.g. https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qPxBNAA0/custom-buttons-on-custom-objects-need-to-provide-backgroundcontext
        const backgroundContext = await this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.originalPageReference);

        // This is the whole point: default the parent Id
        // See e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-navigate-default
        const defaultFieldValues = {};
        defaultFieldValues[PARENT_ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.parentRecordId;

        // The page reference with pieces modified
        const newPageReference = {
            type: this.pageReference.type,
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: this.pageReference.attributes?.objectApiName,
                actionName: this.pageReference.attributes?.actionName
            },
            state: {
                backgroundContext,
                defaultFieldValues: encodeDefaultFieldValues(defaultFieldValues),
                nooverride: '1'
            }
        }

        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](newPageReference);
    }
}

This relies on:

The not (AFAIK) documented backgroundContext parameter (that both keeps the expected background and leaves the user in the right place on "Cancel")
The not (AFAIK) documented inContextOfRef parameter (to find the previous URL information)
The documented ability to default field values in the URL (to set the parent field in the "New" page)

and it is the Aura component that has to be configured as the "New" action:


Thanks. FYI, urlAddressable is indeed available in LWC as of winter'24: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_UrlAddressable.htm&language=en_US&release=250&type=5

@joacoiudica good to know - I've updated the answer. We want to move to LWR so one less barrier.
